# getting Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization using REST service

Tags: apex, rest-api

why below REST web service does not properly deserialize the input argument?Please help me out?

```
 @RestResource(urlMapping='/HH_Survey/*')
        global class HH_SurveyController {


      public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) 
       {
            return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
        }


        @HttpGet
        global static List<Test_Survey__c> getSurvey() {
            RestRequest req=RestContext.request;
            RestResponse res=RestContext.response;
             res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
             String surveyid =req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexof('/')+1);
            List<Test_Survey__c> Survey= [SELECT Id,Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp__c,Test_Field_Investigator_Name__c,Test_Supervisor_Name__c,Test_Respondent_Name__c,Test_Consent_Status__c from Test_Survey__c];
            return Survey;
        }


        @HttpPost              
        global static String createNewSurvey(String Hamlet_Segment_Camp,String Field_Investigator_Name,String Supervisor_Name,String Respondent_Name,String Consent_Status) 
        {
            Test_Survey__c t = new Test_Survey__c();

            t.Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp__c = Hamlet_Segment_Camp;
            t.Test_Field_Investigator_Name__c = Field_Investigator_Name;
            t.Test_Supervisor_Name__c= Supervisor_Name;
            t.Test_Respondent_Name__c= Respondent_Name;
            t.Test_Consent_Status__c= Consent_Status;

           // w.Test_Date_of_the_survey__c= Date_of_the_survey;

            insert t;

            return t.id;
       }
```

**test class**

```
    @IsTest
    public class JSON2Apex_Test {

      public static testMethod void testParse() {
            String json = '{ '+
            '\"args\":{'+
            '  \"Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp\" : \"Hamlet\",'+
            '  \"Test_Field_Investigator_Name\" : \"Investigator \",'+
            '  \"Test_Supervisor_Name\" : \"Supervisor\",'+
            '  \"Test_Respondent_Name\" : \"Respondent \",'+
            '  \"Test_Consent_Status\" : 1'+
            '       }'+

            '}';


            JSON2Apex obj = JSON2Apex.parse(json);
            System.assert(obj != null);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Can you remove all backslash \ from json and try.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the JSON names match the class property names.

So instead of e.g.:

```
        '  \"Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp__c\" : \"Hamlet\",'+
```

it should be:

```
        '  \"Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp\" : \"Hamlet\",'+
```

to match the property name:

```
    public String Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp;
```

**PS**

Looked at your code again. Using the `@HttpPost` annotation signals that the platform should automatically deserialize JSON input into the parameters of the methods - you do not need to write code for that so the `JSON2Apex` class is redundant.

In unit tests, you just directly call the `createNewSurvey` method passing the individual values. In normal use, the JSON you would need to send is:

```
{
    "Test_Hamlet_Segment_Camp" : "Hamlet",
    ...
}
```

i.e. the `args` level is not needed.

Comment: i have corrected my test class but still facing this "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization" Error

Comment: i have removed the JSON2APEX class & args level but still facing same issue

Comment: P.S You don't escape `"` in Apex, since it is not a reserved character.